# Installing ScrollMagic into a Sails.js generated web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, scrollmagic

I am useing Node.js and sailsjs

I want to use ScrollMagic (http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) in my work, to make use of the scrollbar (parallax and such).

I haven't been able to understand from the documentation of both just how to enable the functions.

I tried "npm install scrollmagic" in my app's folder and I also tried manually copying the .js files into both my assets/js and my assets/js/dependancies.

Both did not seem to do make it work.

This is my repository on github https://github.com/yhattav/Vitae

Thanks for your time and help!
Yonatan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found in the documentation:

> To implement animations, ScrollMagic can work with multiple frameworks. The recommended solution is the Greensock Animation Platform (GSAP) due to its stability and feature richness. For a more lightweight approach the VelocityJS framework is also supported. Alternatively custom extensions can be implemented or the necessity of a framework can be completely avoided by animating simply using CSS and class toggles.

So you need to go here:
http://greensock.com/gsap and download the `TweenMax` library and add it as a js dependency to your project's assets.

Plus, you have a small typo in your main.js file:
`ScrollMagic.scene` should be with a capital s, like this `ScrollMagic.Scene`

Comment: This totally worked. did i need to put the scrollmagic files in the dependencies or in js? ( i put them in both and I'd rather know for the next time)

Comment: There is not simple rule for that. Use the dependencies folder for files that need to be loaded before your scripts (e.g. jQuery, lodash and sails.io). In general, if your file does not use any of the dependencies it should be placed in the dependencies folder.